# Conservation of momentum in different reference frames

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

Does the total momentum of a system in a given inertial reference frame have the same numerical value in other inertial reference frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the total momentum does not remain the same in different inertial frames of reference. This is due to the fact that you can boost to a frame with different momentum (you don't need special relativity for this, even basic treatment of relative velocities will do). A simple way to understand this is if you are measuring the momentum of a car standing next to you. If the car is stationary relative to you, you will measure their momentum as 0 (v = 0). But as soon as you start moving with a velocity of 5 ms^-1 to the left, you will measure the car moving with a velocity of 5 ms^-1 to the right, and you will measure them gaining a momentum of 5m (where m is their mass). Relativistic treatment yields a different value, but in any case the actual value of momentum is not necessarily the same for different inertial frames if reference.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. If a particle is moving with velocity $v$ in the $x$ direction, you can boost along the same direction and get to a new frame where the particle has zero momentum. That you can change reference frames and change value of momentum you measure in the new frame is an important fact to realize. For instance, kinematic concepts like [center of momentum frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center-of-momentum_frame) are used profusely in particle physics scattering problems.