# What is boosting using reference frames and what is the significance?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I keep seeing the mentions of boosting velocity / momentum by changing reference frames and I can not understand what people are talking about. For example the answer in [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473660/conservation-of-momentum-in-different-reference-frames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are watching a particle flying through space at a velocity $v$ (importantly, $v<c$). Let's say I am also looking at the same particle, but to me it is stationary. Who is correct? Is the particle moving or not? As it turns out we are both right, the only meaningful way to talk about velocity is *relative velocity*. The particle is neither "objectively" moving nor is it "objectively" stationary, because different observers will give you different answers depending on their relative velocity to the particle.

Me and you are in different reference frames, if you wanted to change your reference frame you would need to be travelling relative to your old reference frame at a velocity $v$. In other words you would have to give a "boost" to yourself so that your velocity relative to your old frame of reference was $v$. Mathematically this is done with the [Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).